# Как передавать данные из input_text в callback другого элемента?

Tags: python, dearpygui

Всех приветствую.
Есть три модуля: `Interface`, `DataManager` и `General`
Для упрощения понимания нарисовал схему взаимодействия между ними. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерфейс написан на [dearpygui](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) и имеет следующий код:

```
class Interface():    
    def draw_main_window(self, start_programm): 
        with dpg.window(label="Example Window", width=1000, height=500, tag='main_wind'):
            with dpg.tab_bar():
                with dpg.tab(label='Main'):
                    with dpg.group():
                        dpg.add_text(default_value="Last Date")
                        dpg.add_input_text(tag='date_user', no_spaces = True, decimal= True, width=100)
                        dpg.add_button(label="Поиск", callback=start_program, user_data = dpg.get_value('date_user')) 

            dpg.set_primary_window(window='main_wind', value=True)
            dpg.setup_dearpygui()
            dpg.show_viewport()
            dpg.start_dearpygui()
            dpg.destroy_context()
```

В модуле `DataManager` находится внутреннее устройство работы программы, которое в данный момент для упрощения ситуации я заменил на тривиальное

```
class DataManager: 
    def start_program(self, sender, app_data, user_data): 
        print(user_data)
        print(sender)
        print(app_data)
```

Класс General выглядит следующим образом:

```
class General():
    def __init__(self, data_manager: DataManager, interface: Interface) -> None:
        self.data_manager = data_manager
        self.interface = interface

    def start_program(self): 
        self.interface.draw_main_window(self.data_manager.start_program)
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = General(SelFlashManager(), GraphInterface())
    t.start_program()
```

Я ожидаю, что по нажатии на кнопку "Поиск" данные из текстового поля `"date_user"` отправятся вместе с `callback` в `start_program` из `DataManager`, но этого не происходит.
По нажатии на кнопку я получаю

```
      # Пустая строка 
31    # id элемента 
None  # Результат
```

Подозреваю, что это из-за выполнения функции get_value в момент инициализации окна. Почитал о том, что есть [отладка обратных вызовов](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/item-callbacks.html). Но основной цикл событий всё равно придётся где-то вызывать, а делать это в `General` как-то странно, ибо весь интерфейс собран внутри `Interface`. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы данные с текстового поля поступали в функцию вместе с `callback`(во время нажатия)?

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой строке:

```
dpg.add_button(label="Поиск", callback=start_program, user_data=dpg.get_value('date_user'))
```

значение для параметра `user_data` "вычисляется" один раз при выполнении этой строки (при создании кнопки), и больше в процессе работы программы не изменяется.

Вам нужно чтобы вместо этого значение вычислялось при нажатии на кнопку. Это можно реализовать, например, передачей в колбэк лямбды, внутри которой вычисляется это значение и передается в настоящий колбэк, тогда значение будет вычисляться непосредственно при нажатии:

```
dpg.add_button(label="Поиск", callback=lambda sender, app_data: start_program(sender, app_data, dpg.get_value('date_user')))
```